# JTextArea not updating when selection changes in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to add a class for each course in the drop down menu on the right corner of the image, as shown in the code in the action Performed there is one class but the same class opens for all the courses so how can i make each one of them open a different class?

this part is confusing me im not sure if i need to do anything with it or not

```
for (String crse : course) {
            courseList.addItem(crse);
        }
        courseList.setFont(fnt);
        courseList.setMaximumSize(courseList.getPreferredSize());
        courseList.addActionListener(this);
        courseList.setActionCommand("Course");
        menuBar.add(courseList);
```

the list of courses in the left corner works perfectly fine with me but my only problem is instead of the list on the left i want the list on the right to work and it has something to do with crse 
[image: screen shot]

```
public class CourseWork extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    CommonCode cc = new CommonCode();
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JTextArea txtNewNote = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea txtDisplayNotes = new JTextArea();
    JTextField search = new JTextField();
    ArrayList<String> note = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> course = new ArrayList<>();
    JComboBox courseList = new JComboBox();
    String crse = "";
    AllNotes allNotes = new AllNotes();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is required for the coursework.
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Racha Chaouby");
        CourseWork prg = new CourseWork();
    }

    // Using MVC
    public CourseWork() {
        model();
        view();
        controller();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if ("Close".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
        }
        if ("Course".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            crse = courseList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            COMP1752 cw = new COMP1752();
        }

        if ("Exit".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if ("NewNote".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            addNote(txtNewNote.getText());
            txtNewNote.setText("");
        }
        if ("SearchKeyword".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            String lyst = allNotes.searchAllNotesByKeyword("", 0, search.getText());
            txtDisplayNotes.setText(lyst);
        }
        if ("Coursework".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            CWDetails cw = new CWDetails();

        }
        if ("Course1752".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            COMP1752 cw = new COMP1752();

        }
        if ("Course1753".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            COMP1753 cw = new COMP1753();

        }
        if ("Cours1110".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            MATH1110 cw = new MATH1110();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyTyped not coded yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyPressed not coded yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyReleased not coded yet.");
    }

    private void model() {
        course.add("COMP1752");
        course.add("COMP1753");
        course.add("MATH1110");
        crse = course.get(0);

        //Note nt = new Note();
        //nt.noteID = 1;
        //t.dayte = getDateAndTime();
        //nt.course = crse;
        //nt.note = "Arrays are of fixed length and are inflexible.";
        //allNotes.allNotes.add(nt);
        //nt = new Note();
        //nt.noteID = 2;
        //nt.dayte = getDateAndTime();
        //nt.course = crse;
        //nt.note = "ArraysList can be added to and items can be deleted.";
        //allNotes.allNotes.add(nt);
    }

    private void view() {
        Font fnt = new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 24);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu kurs = new JMenu();
        kurs = new JMenu("Courses");
        kurs.setToolTipText("Course tasks");
        kurs.setFont(fnt);

        kurs.add(makeMenuItem("COMP1752", "Course1752", "Coursework requirments.", fnt));
        kurs.add(makeMenuItem("COMP1753", "Course1753", "Coursework requirments.", fnt));
        kurs.add(makeMenuItem("MATH1110", "Course1110", "Coursework requirments.", fnt));
        menuBar.add(kurs);

        JMenu note = new JMenu();
        note = new JMenu("Note");
        note.setToolTipText("Note tasks");
        note.setFont(fnt);

        note.add(makeMenuItem("New", "NewNote", "Create a new note.", fnt));
        note.addSeparator();
        note.add(makeMenuItem("Close", "Close", "Clear the current note.", fnt));

        menuBar.add(note);
        menuBar.add(makeMenuItem("Exit", "Exit", "Close this program", fnt));

        // This will add each course to the combobox
        for (String crse : course) {
            courseList.addItem(crse);
        }
        courseList.setFont(fnt);
        courseList.setMaximumSize(courseList.getPreferredSize());
        courseList.addActionListener(this);
        courseList.setActionCommand("Course");
        menuBar.add(courseList);

        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        // Setting up the ButtonBar
        JButton button = null;
        button = makeButton("Document", "Coursework",
                "Open the coursework window.",
                "Coursework");
        toolBar.add(button);

        button = makeButton("Create", "NewNote",
                "Create a new note.",
                "New");
        toolBar.add(button);
        button = makeButton("closed door", "Close",
                "Close this note.",
                "Close");
        toolBar.add(button);
        toolBar.addSeparator();
        button = makeButton("exit button", "Exit",
                "Exit from this program.",
                "Exit");
        toolBar.add(button);

        toolBar.addSeparator();
        // This forces anything after it to the right.
        toolBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        search.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(6900, 30));
        search.setFont(fnt);
        toolBar.add(search);
        toolBar.addSeparator();
        button = makeButton("search", "SearchKeyword",
                "Search for this text.",
                "Search");
        toolBar.add(button);

        add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel pnlWest = new JPanel();
        pnlWest.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlWest, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pnlWest.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        txtNewNote.setFont(fnt);
        pnlWest.add(txtNewNote);

        JButton btnAddNote = new JButton("Add note");
        btnAddNote.setActionCommand("NewNote");
        btnAddNote.addActionListener(this);
        pnlWest.add(btnAddNote);

        add(pnlWest, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel cen = new JPanel();
        cen.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cen, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        cen.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        txtDisplayNotes.setFont(fnt);
        cen.add(txtDisplayNotes);

        add(cen, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Coursework");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);  // Needed to ensure that the items can be seen.

    }

    private void controller() {
        addAllNotes();
    }

    protected JMenuItem makeMenuItem(
            String txt,
            String actionCommand,
            String toolTipText,
            Font fnt) {

        JMenuItem mnuItem = new JMenuItem();
        mnuItem.setText(txt);
        mnuItem.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
        mnuItem.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
        mnuItem.setFont(fnt);
        mnuItem.addActionListener(this);
        return mnuItem;
    }

    protected JButton makeButton(
            String imageName,
            String actionCommand,
            String toolTipText,
            String altText) {

        //Create and initialize the button.
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
        button.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        //Look for the image.
        String imgLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "\\icons\\"
                + imageName
                + ".png";

        File fyle = new File(imgLocation);
        if (fyle.exists() && !fyle.isDirectory()) {
            // image found
            Icon img;
            img = new ImageIcon(imgLocation);
            button.setIcon(img);
        } else {
            // image NOT found
            button.setText(altText);
            System.err.println("Resource not found: " + imgLocation);
        }

        return button;
    }

    private void addNote(String text) {
        allNotes.addNote(allNotes.getMaxID(), crse, text);
        addAllNotes();
    }

    private void addAllNotes() {
        String txtNotes = "";

        for (Note n : allNotes.getAllNotes()) {
            txtNotes += n.getNote() + "\n";
        }
        txtDisplayNotes.setText(txtNotes);

    }

    public String getDateAndTime() {
        String UK_DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        String ukDateAndTime;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat uksdf = new SimpleDateFormat(UK_DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
        ukDateAndTime = uksdf.format(cal.getTime());

        return ukDateAndTime;
    }

}
```

code snippet
this is the AllNotes class:

```
public class AllNotes extends CommonCode {

    private ArrayList<Note> allNotes = new ArrayList<>();
    private String crse = "";
    private int maxID = 0;

    AllNotes() {
        readAllNotes();
    }

    public final int getMaxID() {
        maxID++;
        return maxID;
    }

    private void readAllNotes() {
        ArrayList<String> readNotes = new ArrayList<>();

        readNotes = readTextFile(appDir + fileSeparator + "Notes.txt");
        System.out.println(readNotes.get(0));

        if (!"File not found".equals(readNotes.get(0))) {
            allNotes.clear();
            for (String str : readNotes) {
                String[] tmp = str.split("\t");

                int nid = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
                Note n = new Note(nid, tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3]);
                allNotes.add(n);

                if (nid > maxID) {
                    maxID = nid;


                }
            }
        }
        maxID++;
    }

    public void addNote(int maxID, String course, String note) {
        Note myNote = new Note(maxID, course, note);
        allNotes.add(myNote);
        writeAllNotes();
    }

    public ArrayList<Note> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }

    private void writeAllNotes() {
        String path = appDir + fileSeparator +"Notes.txt";
        ArrayList<String> writeNote = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Note n : allNotes) {
            String tmp = n.getNoteID() + "\t";
            tmp += n.getCourse() + "\t";
            tmp += n.getDayte() + "\t";
            tmp += n.getNote();
            writeNote.add(tmp);
        }
        try {
            writeTextFile(path, writeNote);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem! " + path);
        }
    }

    public String searchAllNotesByKeyword(String noteList, int i, String s) {
        if (i == allNotes.size()) {
            return noteList;
        }
        if (allNotes.get(i).getNote().contains(s)) {
            noteList += allNotes.get(i).getNote() + "\n";
        }

        return searchAllNotesByKeyword(noteList, i + 1, s);
    }

}
```

Comment: That is a *lot* of source code (not quite minimal, complete and verifiable), but one thing I noticed is that you're creating objects in the ìf`statements, that are then immediately discarded because you reach the end of the block.

Comment: You need to explain the behaviour of the program. As I understand each line f text in your image is a note, and you store notes for each course, and you want that when you select a course, only the notes for this course shows up. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Bentaye yes that is correct, so what i am trying to do is to connect the class into to the course the class is ready but i cant figure out how to connect them T_T

Comment: @CutieLaft Have a look at my answer, might work. If not can you edit your question with the code of the classes `COMP1752`, `Note` and `AllNotes`?

Comment: @Bentaye i tried your code but it didnt work it only shows the comp1752 class and it wont take me to the main class, ive edited my question with so you can take a look. thanks for your help :)

Comment: @CutieLaft I updated my answer, have a look

Answer (score 0):

When you init your drop down of `courses`, set the action command to be the same value that you record in your file, this will make everything consistent when looking up notes from the file. so this way

```
kurs.add(makeMenuItem("Course 1752", "COMP1752", "Coursework requirments.", fnt));
kurs.add(makeMenuItem("Course 1753", "COMP1753", "Coursework requirments.", fnt));
kurs.add(makeMenuItem("Course 1110", "MATH1110", "Coursework requirments.", fnt));
```

Then change `actionPerformed` to store the selected value form the drop down to the `crse` attribute, and call `addAllNotes()` to refresh the notes list

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    System.out.println("actionPerformed: " + ae.getActionCommand());

    if ("Close".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {

    } else if ("Course".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
        // set the value of the selected element into the crse attribute
        crse = courseList.getSelectedItem().toString();
        // Refresh the text area
        addAllNotes();

    } else if ("Exit".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
        System.exit(0);

    } else if ("NewNote".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
        addNote(txtNewNote.getText());
        txtNewNote.setText("");

    } else if ("SearchKeyword".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
        String lyst = allNotes.searchAllNotesByKeyword("", 0, search.getText());
        txtDisplayNotes.setText(lyst);

    } else if ("Coursework".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
        CWDetails cw = new CWDetails();

    }

    System.out.println("selectedCourse: " + crse);
}
```

in `AllNotes`, create a new method to return the notes for a specific course.

```
public ArrayList<Note> getAllNotesForCourse(String course) {
    ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Note note : allNotes) {
        if(course.equalsIgnoreCase(note.getCourse())) {
            notes.add(note);
        }
    }
    return notes;
}
```

then in the `addAllNotes` method, call `getAllNotesForCourse`, passing the selected course. This will update `txtDisplayNotes` with the notes from the selected course

```
private void addAllNotes() {
    String txtNotes = "";

    for (Note n : allNotes.getAllNotesForCourse(crse)) {
        txtNotes += n.getNote() + "\n";
    }
    txtDisplayNotes.setText(txtNotes);

}
```

I think this is all I modified and it works for me.